# how to block the possibility of adding the same values ​to the database python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x

how to block the possibility of adding the same values ​​to the database, for example e-mail addresses in python and MySQL?

Comment: make the email column UNIQUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From database perspective, you would typically put a unique constraint on the corresponding table column:

```
create table users (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null unique
);
```

With this set up in place, any query that would attempt generating a duplicate `email` (either from an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`) would fail with a unique contraint violation error.